# Limited resources for learning Fanuc Macro B programming, I need some direction as to how people learn this language

Tags: cnc

Why is it that the only 2 books on CNC macro programming are by Peter Smid and one S K Sinha. Am I looking at this the wrong way? What am I missing? Is Macro programming one single thing that can be applied to CNC?

Comment: So what resources do Fanuc supply?

Comment: Theres this: https://www.cncci.com/fanuc-cert-custom-macro-book

But my question remains. Wheres all the textbooks for CNC programming the way C++ is treated?

Comment: C++ is a standard programming language used by many. Most CNC languages are proprietary and used by relatively few users (compared to general purpose programming).

Comment: There are no books because the only people who are likely to need to know this are computer programmers writing CAD/CAM software. Both the books you mention are about 10 years old. Working in an engineering company in the UK, this sort of CNC programming by hand rather than direct from CAD software died out 20 or 30 years ago.

Comment: I take your points, its dated or its too specific. Mind you, Smid himself says Macro does not compete with CAD/CAM programming but complements it. And here is a current reputable resource that agrees: https://www.cnccookbook.com/37-things-cam-wont-gcode-programming-can/

Part of my question still remains, what is the path to learning this language as those programmers who program CAD/CAM see it? those people who can go beyond that FANUC book. Are they using C++ to program CAD/CAM? 

And is the C++ programmer the one that would most readily learn CNC Macro?

Comment: CNC programming creates G code.  You can do this by hand or via software.  I'd rather correct the tool paths in software, where I can see the impacts, rather than creating my own via macros.  As for programming, you are trying to equate a programming language like C++ to a program application creating G code.